# Align sentences of paragraph

Tags: math-mode, indentation, sections-paragraphs

I have a paragraph called 'a)'. Next to the 'a)' there is a formula. Then in the same paragraph, but on the next line I have another formula, but I want this to begin at the same place as the first formula. Right now, the second formula starts underneath the 'a)'. But I want it to align and start right underneath the first formula.

I hope you guys get it and have a solution.

```
\paragraph{a)}
$f(x)=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{4x-1}}$ \\
$g(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{2x+5}$
```

Comment: Try reading the amsmath manual (see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think you're better off using a list than to set this using `\paragraph`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of what you are after, but...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \paragraph{a)}
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
       &f(x)=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{4x-1}} \\
       &g(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{2x+5}
     \end{aligned}
    $
\end{document}
```

[image]